# INSTALLED_APPS error in mongoengine code

Tags: django, python-2.7, mongoengine

I was working on Django 1.3.1 with mongodb.

I installed following:

> django-bootstrap-toolkit==2.5.6 django-email-extras==0.1.8
>   django-forms-builder==0.7.15 django-pagination==1.0.7
>
> django-grappelli==2.4.2 docutils==0.9.1 python-memcached==1.48
>   sphinx-me==0.1.2 wsgiref==0.1.2 django-rte==0.4.0

Suddenly I got following error. Any help .

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_mongodb_engine-0.4.0-py2.7.egg/django_mongodb_engine/**init**.py", line 13, in 
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS.insert(0, 'django_mongodb_engine')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'

I tried to convert INSTALLED_APPS as list instead of tuple, but it does not worked .

Comment: django 3.1? I don't think so :)

Answer (score 0):

It was because after installing the modules , django is updated to 1.4.1 , So to degrade the version :

```
>>> import django 
>>> django.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc
```

> ```
> 1) Remove the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django
> ```
>
> `2) Install 1.3.1 again